# Apache URL rewrite fails if exclamation mark at end

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my rewrite rule:

```
    RewriteRule ^([a-z-\s]+)/([A-Za-z-\s]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z-\s]+)/?$  index.php?lang=$1&page_name=$2&propertyID=$3    [NC,L]
```

The last element of the URL is the title of the property deal, e.g. "three-bedroom-flat-in-a-beautiful-location". Everything works as expected... unless there is an exclamation mark at the end of the title.

This URL works fine:

```
mysite/bg/let/1/Ne-izpuskajte-tazi-oferta
```

But this returns the "404 Not Found" error page:

```
mysite/bg/let/1/Ne-izpuskajte-tazi-oferta!
```

I also tested it with a question mark, and it works fine:

```
mysite/bg/let/1/Ne-izpuskajte-tazi-oferta?
```

The last pattern -- `([A-Za-z-\s]+)` -- doesn't expect any punctuation marks but it doesn't play any role in resolving the URL.

What should I do? Instruct the administrator who will be adding/editing properties not to use any exclamation marks in the title? Or is there a programmatic way to deal with this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You last capture group doesnt match ! , see how i fixed it 

`RewriteRule ^([a-z-\s]+)/([A-Za-z-\s]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z-\s!]+)/?$ `

Comment: @starkeen Thanks for the edit! Yes, the problem is resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`([A-Za-z-\s]+)` matches `[A-Za-z-\s]` 1 or more times, where `[..]` is any character in the range A-Z, a-z, the literal - character or whitespace. You find that there is no exclamation mark in there. Since that regex does not match, it will not rewrite. The simple fix is to add the exclamation mark to the regex: `([A-Za-z!-\s]+)`.

So why does `mysite/bg/let/1/Ne-izpuskajte-tazi-oferta?` work? Well... in an url, the `?` is a reserved character. It marks where the query string starts. The `RewriteRule` is always matched against the part after the hostname and the common prefix (based on .htaccess location, or specific `<directory>` context) and before the query string. For that url, it is matched against `bg/let/1/Ne-izpuskajte-tazi-oferta`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!